# Git Merge doesn't merge all files from other branch

Tags: git

So this is my situation.

My .gitignore is empty.
I have the A branch from which I created a new branch B, 10 days ago. Today I want to merge the A branch into branch B to keep in sync. However, when I try to use the merge command I notice that there are files that are not included in the merge although they are different in A and B.

When i try to see the differences between my branches with the command git diff --name-status A, the files are included.

Is this a common issue? How can this be solved?

Comment: So there has been commits to branch A after the commit you created branch B from? Are you sure you haven't changed the same files in commits to B?

Comment: Yes, other devs have pushed code to branch A while I was working on branch B. I have checked and I have not touched the files that aren't included in the merge since I made the branch.

Comment: This can happen when files are modified in both branches with a possibility of merge conflict.

Comment: @22kar I haven't modified the files in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some troubleshooting I found the cause to the problem.

I noticed in the visual representation of the last commit that a 3rd branch had been merged into my branch, when I did a `git reset HEAD~` it undid the changes of my last commit and I saw in the sourcetree UI that there was a difference of 22 commits with the remote of my branch. I then started a new branch C from B, committed my unstaged changes and merged A back into C.